# Injeção de Dependência - Error: InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type

Tags: asp.net-core, ddd, code-first, automapper

Amigos, mais um vez venho pedir ajuda de vocês.

Ao tentar chamar uma Action do meu Controller estou recebendo o problema descrito abaixo:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Muo.Application.Interfaces.ICompanyService' while attempting to
>   activate 'Muo.Presentation.Web.Controllers.CompanyController'.
>       Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
>   sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

Pelo que parece ser o problema é na Injeção de Dependência. No entanto, estou achando estranho, pois estou fazendo isso com o AutoMapper. Abaixo segue minhas classes:

In Application Layer - Parte referente ao AutoMapper

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public DomainToViewModelMappingProfile()
    {
         //Transformo minha entidade numa ViewModel
         CreateMap<Company, CompanyViewModel>();
    }
}


public class ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile()
    {
         //Transformo minha ViewModel em Entidade de Domínio
         CreateMap<CompanyViewModel, RegisterNewCompanyCommand>()
                .ConstructUsing(c => new RegisterNewCompanyCommand(c.OficialName, c.Nickname, c.Cnpj, c.Type, c.StateRegistration, c.DistrictRegistration));
         CreateMap<CompanyViewModel, UpdateCompanyCommand>()
                .ConstructUsing(c => new UpdateCompanyCommand(c.Id, c.OficialName, c.Nickname, c.Cnpj, c.Type, c.StateRegistration, c.DistrictRegistration));       
    }
}


public static class AutoMapperSetup
{
    public static void AddAutoMapperSetup(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (services == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));

        services.AddAutoMapper();

        AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
    }
}
```

Na Camada de Apresentação, na classe Startup.cs do projeto ASP.NET Core, registro o serviço do AutoMapper conforme abaixo:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   //...

   services.AddAutoMapperSetup();
}
```

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Me ajudem por favor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faltou você registrar a interface  `ICompanyService`. Para demais dúvidas consulte a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddScoped<ICompanyService, CompanyService>();
   services.AddAutoMapperSetup();
}
```

O primeiro tipo genérico representa o tipo (normalmente uma interface) que será solicitado a partir do contêiner. O segundo tipo genérico representa o tipo concreto que será instanciado pelo contêiner e usado para atender a essas solicitações.

Os serviços ASP.NET podem ser configurados com as seguintes vidas úteis:

**Transient**

Objetos `Transient` são sempre diferentes; uma nova instância é fornecida para todos os controladores e todos os serviços.

**Scoped**

Objetos com `Scoped` são os mesmos em uma solicitação, mas diferentes entre solicitações diferentes

**Singleton**

Objetos `singleton` são os mesmos para cada objeto e cada solicitação (independentemente de uma instância ser fornecida `ConfigureServices`)

[Fonte](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/20/asp-net-core-error-invalidoperationexception-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-foo-while-attempting-to-activate-bar/)